# How do i random a number in a string?

Tags: string, random, c++-cli

I´m trying to set a random number in a string, but idk how i can let the program know that i want the random number and not the letter n.

Im using visual studio 2008 , Windows Forms C++

```cpp
System::Drawing::Font ^Fuente = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial Black",50);
System::Random ^r = gcnew System::Random(System::DateTime::Now.Ticks);
char n=r->Next(1,100);
buffer->Graphics->DrawString("n",Fuente,System::Drawing::Brushes::WhiteSmoke,50,50);,50);
```

Comment: umm , sorry if my concepts are wrong, first of all im not an english speaker . Its a bit difficult to explain in cientific words. If you know what do i mean, then try to help me...

Comment: Narrowing down an issue into component parts is not a skill restricted to native speakers of English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System::Drawing::Font ^Fuente = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial Black",50);
System::Random ^r = gcnew System::Random(System::DateTime::Now.Ticks);
int n=r->Next(1,100);
buffer->Graphics->DrawString(n.ToString(), Fuente, System::Drawing::Brushes::WhiteSmoke,50,50);,50);
```

Might be what you are after

Comment: @Giuseppe: you can upvote helpful answers and _accept_ answers that solved you problem. It's what makes stack overflow work. Cheers (see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: sehe, when i try to compile this, it gives me a lot of errors. 
why did you declare the int as "Int^ n? ikn if its a visual studio problem. Cause i cant se anithing from n->

Comment: yes, i know that but i need 15 rep. Im only 6 yet. I will give you point when i head to 15. Thanks for your time .

Comment: @Giuseppe: sorry, that is surprising 'logic'. No harm done, m8

Comment: can you tell me why did you used System::int32? , it cause im making a game for my final in college. And probably they will ask me why ...

Comment: Sehe, id want to make the font more transparent. What function do i hav to use?

Comment: @sehe : That should be `int` or `System::Int32`, no `^` -- `^` is for reference types, `int`/`Int32` is a value type, so you're boxing the value unnecessarily.

Comment: @sehe : `int n = ...; n.ToString();` does what you want, without unnecessary heap allocation. `int^ n = ...; n->ToString();` is valid (boxing is implicit in C++/CLI), just inefficient.

Comment: @ildjarn: oh - c++-cli is always simpler than I expect. Can you tell I have been doing (D)COM(+) and managed extensions (2005) only... Thanks for teaching me this.

Answer (score 0):

You're using quotes when drawing string - that's a string literal.

You should convert your number to a string using stdlib.h itoa function.

```
char number[3];
int n = r->Next(1,100);
itoa(n, number, 10); //number to convert, string to save value in, base
buffer->Graphics->DrawString(number,Fuente,System::Drawing::Brushes::WhiteSmoke,50,50);,50);
```

Comment: Draskvic, how do i do this string, but when it prints on the screen it looks more transparent?

Comment: -1 `itoa` is nonstandard, and wholly unnecessary in this case -- `n.ToString()` would return a string of the _proper_ type (yours isn't, and as a result your code wouldn't compile).

Comment: @ildjarn: There's an implicit converting constructor `String(char*)`, is there not?

Comment: @Ben : There's an _explicit_ converting constructor; attempting to pass a `char[3]` directly yields an error e.g. `error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [3]' to 'System::String ^'`.